# Visual Studio Installer Download Stops at 5MB

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, visual-studio-2017, installation

I am running Windows 7 with the Service Package using Visual Studio 2017.

Anything that I try to install using Visual Studio Installer just stops downloading once it reaches 5MB and the error message will disappear too quickly for me to read it. I am not an Administrator.

A few suggestions I have searched have told me to look through a 'Certificates' folder but I do not seem to have this folder in my program files. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had an administrator come to my computer and run the installer, and it worked just fine.

Comment: This answer dosen't tell anything